# Trying to Create a Battleship Program with Java

Tags: java

```
public class BattleshipGrid
{
    public static final int OUT_OF_BOUNDS = -1;

    // values to be used in the 2D grid
    public static final int EMPTY = 0;
    public static final int SHIP = 1;
    public static final int HIT = 2;
    public static final int MISS = 3;
```

I need to create a nested for loop that allows for each element of my 10 x 10 Battleship grid to be set to the value for EMPTY (so 0). How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

How do you store the grid? If it's a multidimensional array, something like this will work:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    grid[i][j] = EMPTY;
```

I would suggest to use an Enum for values by the way.

Comment: Wouldn't a int[][] be initialises with '0's ;)

Comment: @Madprogrammer yes, but this answer is still valid if enums are used instead of integers

Comment: Ah, but then it becomes a different question, you implementation is kind of wasting time an effort based on the basic requirements, didn't say it was wrong ;)